# Perl: problem with sockets

Tags: perl, sockets

apologize for my English.
I have some problem with sockets.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use POSIX;
use POSIX ":sys_wait_h";
use IO::Socket;
use IO::Handle;
use DBI;

my $pid= fork();
exit() if $pid;
die "Couldn't fork: $! " unless defined($pid);

POSIX::setsid() or die "Can't start a new session $!";
my $time_to_die =0;
my $server;

sub signal_handler {
    $time_to_die = 1;
    close($server);
}

$SIG{INT}= $SIG{TERM} = \&signal_handler;

sub REAPER {
    while ((my $waitedpid = waitpid(-1,WNOHANG)) > 0) { }
    $SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;
}

my $server_port = 6741;
$server= new IO::Socket::INET(LocalPort     => $server_port,
                              TYPE      => SOCK_STREAM,
                  Reuse     => 1,
                  Listen    => 10) or die "Couldn't be a tcp server on port $server_port: $@\n";

until($time_to_die) {
    my $client;

    while($client = $server->accept()) {
        $SIG{CHLD} = \&REAPER;    
        defined(my $child_pid=fork()) or die "Can't fork new child $!";
        next if $child_pid;

        if($child_pid == 0) {
            close($server);
        }

        $client->autoflush(1);
        print $client "Command :";

        while(<$client>) {
            next unless /\S/;

        my $full_enter_str = $_;
        chomp($full_enter_str);

            if($full_enter_str =~ /(<\w\d\d\d\w>),(\d{5}),(M|O),(\d{6}),(\d{6}),(\d{4}\.\d{4}\w),(\d{5}\.\d{4}\w),(\d{2}.\d),(\d{3}\.\d),(\d{3}\.\d),(\d),(\d{2})/) {
                my $dbm = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=homepage;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306", "av", "") or die "MySQL connect error";
                $dbm->do("INSERT INTO `new_table` VALUES (NULL, '".$1."')");
                $dbm->disconnect();
            }
    }
    continue {
      print $client "Command :";
    }
    exit;
}
continue {
    close($client);
}
```

First problem: when i sent a string via telnet-client:

```
<T060M>,00287,M,124427,220411,5800.1577N,04200.1038E,01.0,073.4,196.4,1,69
```

all right then, entry is added to the database. But when the port comes to something like (tcpdump):

```
0x0000:  4500 0073 0003 0000 f606 d057 d557 5cc6  E..s.......W.W\.
0x0010:  c0a8 0164 dcc4 1a55 4016 741d b90a 79e4  ...d...U@.t...y.
0x0020:  5018 2c60 3b1f 0000 3c54 3036 304d 3e2c  P.,`;...<T060M>,
0x0030:  3030 3238 372c 4d2c 3130 3432 3339 2c32  00287,M,104239,2
0x0040:  3430 3431 312c 3537 3434 2e35 3432 384e  40411,5744.5428N
0x0050:  2c30 3431 3030 2e34 3133 3445 2c31 312e  ,04100.4134E,11.
0x0060:  302c 3030 302e 302c 3039 362e 342c 312c  0,000.0,096.4,1,
0x0070:  3646 0d                                  6F.
```

Then nothing happens.

Second problem:
After a while, I see a zombie in sufficient quantity (ps ax | grep '%scriptname%'), even though I know exactly what the client just two.

Answer (score 0):

About the first thing - I am not really sure, but are you sure that it matches the regexp? Your line ends with `6F`, but the regexp ends with `\d{2}`. It doesn't look like it matches.

About the second thing, I am interested too, because the reaper looks like it should work.

edit: AFAIK, setting `$SIG{CHLD}` to `"IGNORE"` is a better solution, because you don't do anything useful in the `REAPER` function anyway. But it doesn't explain why your approach doesn't work.